# meta query not showing any results?

Tags: custom-field, query-posts

I'm trying to show result for a custom field that is not empty on a custom post type but getting no results?

```
                    <?php

                        if (have_posts()) :
                            $args = array(
                                'post_type' => 'programmes',
                                'meta_query' => array(
                                        'key' => 'linktovideocatchup',
                                        'value' => '',
                                        'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'),
                                //'caller_get_posts' => 1,                              
                                );
                        ?>

                        <?php query_posts( $args ); ?>


                        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> `enter code here`
```

Comment: I'll ask the obvious question: have you looked at the `wp_post_meta` table in the DB (using phpMyAdmin or whatever) and verified that you have one (or more) such items? If so, have you then checked the corresponding `id`(s) in `wp_posts` and verified that at least one of them has a `post_type` of `programmes`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you're missing an array within the meta_query element:

```
$args = array(
           'post_type' => 'programmes',
           'meta_query' => array(
                              array(
                                   'key'     => 'linktovideocatchup',
                                   'value'   => '',
                                   'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
                                   )
                              )
            );
```

(this is required to allow for querying of multiple meta fields.)

you also had an extraneous comma after the meta_query array element which can cause problems.

i think you should also be able to use the operator '<>' rather than 'NOT LIKE', i believe it's more efficient.

there's a good write-up on the meta_query functionality here: http://scribu.net/wordpress/advanced-metadata-queries.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a better answer at [How can I show posts only if meta_value is not empty](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10881/how-can-i-show-posts-only-if-meta-value-is-not-empty) - Can't query a null value like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$args = array(
       'post_type' => 'programmes',
       'meta_query' => array(
                          array(
                               'key'     => 'linktovideocatchup',
                               'value'   => '',
                               'compare' => '!='
                               )
                          )
        );
```

Just change 'NOT LIKE' by '!='. It worked for me ;)